# Already plugin PlantUML into my Apache Netbeans 13, still can't use it

Tags: plantuml, netbeans-13

I want to use PlantUML to convert my java code into UML class diagram, I did see there's have PlantUML on the list in Windows.
But when I want to add a new project, there's no UML that I can choose.
I want to know why this happened to my netbeans, and how to solve this problem.
thank you

I searched up lots of information, many people using easyUML rather than PlantUML. Why I use PlantUML is because there's no easyUML service that Apache Netbeans 13 would support.